# C# Race-condition prevention in observer pattern with shared resource

Tags: c#, mutex, race-condition, observer-pattern

I have a threaded WebListener that updates a public variable with the most recent incoming message. I have implemented the class with the observer pattern, so i can notify subscribers when a new message has been received. Each subscriber then can make a decision on whether to retrieve the message from the public variable.

I am concerned with the scenario where:

1. WebListner recieves message 'a'
2. WebListener writes message 'a'
3. WebListener notifies subscriber of received message 'a'
4. Subscriber receives notification of message 'a'
5. WebListener receives another message 'b'
6. WebListener overwrites message 'a' with 'b'
7. WebListener notifies subscriber of received message 'b'
8. Subscriber reads message 'a' but actually gets 'b' **Note - this is 100% fine - we want to receive the latest message (`b`)**
9. Subscriber reads message 'b' and gets 'b' again. **Note - this should not return `b` - it should instead return nothing or throw an exception**

**EDIT: Subscribers should be receiving a new message every time they recall a message after receiving a notification. This is what i tried to solve using a token passed with the notification. If the message from the previous notification has already been overwritten, the outcome should be that the message is not retrieved. At no stage am i wanting messages other than the current message to be retrieved.
**

What is the best way to prevent this in the most efficient way?

I thought of generating a unique token and sending it with the notification to the subscriber to make a COMPARE TOKEN -> READ VALUE kind of action but this creates a race-condition issue with the WebListener overwriting the value between the compare and read actions.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

// Observer design pattern allows objects created from classes that inherit from 
// IObserver to be notified when an event is triggered when subscribed. 
// In this case, the event is when a HTTP message is received on the listenport endpoint.

public interface IObserver
{
    //Receive update from subject
    void Update(ITopic topic);
}

public interface ITopic
{
    //Subscribe an observer to the topic
    void Subscribe(IObserver observer);

    //Unsubscribe a subscriber from the topic
    void Unsubscribe(IObserver observer);

    //Notify all subscribers of an event
    void Notify();
}

// WebListener listens for incoming http messages on the listenport endpoint and notifies subscribers.
// Subscribers can access the message through the public method GetMessage.
public class WebListener : MonoBehaviour, ITopic
{
    string listenport = "http://192.168.1.3:8080";

    private HttpListener listener;
    private Thread listenerThread;

    HttpListenerRequest message;

    void Start()
    {
        listener = new HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add(listenport);
        listener.Start();

        listenerThread = new Thread(startListener);
        listenerThread.Start();

        Debug.Log("WebListener: Listener started");
    }

    private void startListener()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var result = listener.BeginGetContext(ListenerCallback, listener);
            result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        }
    }

    private void ListenerCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        var context = listener.EndGetContext(result);
        ReceiveMessage(context);
        context.Response.Close();
    }

    private void ReceiveMessage(HttpListenerContext context)
    {
        message = context.Request;
    }

    // SUBSCRIBERS WILL CALL THIS TO RETRIEVE MESSAGE
    public HttpListenerRequest GetMessage()
    {
        return message;
    }

    private List<IObserver> _observers = new List<IObserver>();

    // Implement ITopic interface methods
    public void Subscribe(IObserver observer)
    {
        this._observers.Add(observer);
        Debug.Log("WebListener: Added Subscriber");
    }

    public void Unsubscribe(IObserver observer)
    {
        this._observers.Remove(observer);
        Debug.Log("WebListener: Removed Subscriber");
    }

    public void Notify()
    {
        //WAS GOING TO GENERATE TOKEN HERE AND PASS IN THE UPDATE FUNCTION BUT THIS WILL CREATE RACE-CONDITION.
        Debug.Log("WebListener: Notifying subscribers of incoming message");
        foreach (var observer in _observers)
        {
            observer.Update(this);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to include the message in the `Notify` method.

Comment: Messages may be incoming very rapidly in some cases and i didn't want to be multicasting n_subscriber messages a hundred times a second. Easier for the WebListener, maybe. Not easier in terms of system-wide performance.

Comment: Either way you are multicasting n messages...

Comment: Sure, but the overhead is much smaller for a Notify function without a payload. This way i give the subscriber the option to retrieve the payload.

Comment: I would be surprised if it is less overhead to pass a reference to your class over a reference to your message.

Comment: Does `Notify` get called by another thread? Or are your subscribers potentially threaded?

Comment: Potentially Jonathon K, this is supposed to be a generic reusable class that can be dropped into any situation and follows best practice.

Comment: So if you do not want to have List of HttpListenerRequests as Alexei stated below, you need to lock your while(true) thread till the moment when in Notify for loop is finished

Comment: When you store the value, also store a counter. When providing the data also provide the counter. Then, on next request, pass up the previous counter value and only return data if the counter value is different. You'll likely want to use `lock` on the read and write paths to ensure that the data and the counter are in sync. _Also, as a side issue, I am not sure I'd refer to this pattern as an Observer pattern._

Comment: What does it mean to return nothing?  You could have GetMessage take an integer indicating the message being requested, if it doesn't match the current count the return "nothing".  Just be sure to protect the integer with a lock.

Comment: I couldn't understand what you meant. Do you mean to have two counters, one with the listener and another with the subscriber and when they are out of sync, then the subscriber knows that a message is to be retrieved?
I am sure this would work but it relies on a counter being implemented on the subscribers side and i was trying to provide a simple interface that would need little to no implementation on the subscribers side to use. I guess a counter is just as good as anything.

Comment: @Jonathon K i didn't say return nothing, i said a message isn't retrieved. This could be achieved a number of ways, such as an exception being thrown or some kind of application logic that tells the subscriber that a message is ready, such as mjwills counter idea, or a function that returns a boolean to indicate whether a message is ready to be retrieved.

Comment: `i was trying to provide a simple interface that would need little to no implementation on the subscribers side to use` The client has to (some way) pass through where it is up to. Alternatively, the provider of the data could keep a `WeakReference` to each of the subscribers and effectively keep track of where they are up to (i.e. store those counters provider-side rather than in the subscriber) - but that is going to be substantially more complicated to implement.

Comment: How about using [Rx](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive)?

Comment: Interesting @swdon, i will check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really update global state and expect listeners magically get consistent historical values without storing them somehow.

Options:

- change expectations of listeners to "something changed in global state, need to check"
- send change record to listener in the event
- have queue of changes per-listener
- make state immutable and send current state to listeners in the event
- while it may not useful for your particular case, synchronizing receive and notify calls to wait for all "notify" handlers to complete before allowing next "receive" is an option (suggested by [Jonathon K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8723329/jonathon-k))

Comment: Nowhere did i mention i wanted subscribers to get historical values.

Comment: @Raptop then I totally misread your 8/9 lines... You may want to clarify what exactly you expect as success in that case (as you don't consider "a" historical value)...

Comment: One other option would be to make `Notify` and `ReceiveMessage` mutually exclusive with `Monitor` or `lock(...)`

Comment: Sure Alexei, i mean in step 8, that the subscriber attempts to read the message that caused the notification to be triggered. I will clarify

Comment: @JonathonK it does not sound like blocking "receive" is really acceptable for OP here... In general indeed it is a viable option (I'll edit it in)

Comment: I wouldn't have mentioned it, but after their reaction to queuing historical values...

Comment: @Raptop based on your edit and comments the "queue" per subscriber is the only realistic option - this way producer controls what listeners get. I.e. if you have queues of at most single item (last or empty) you achieve your goal of getting the latest state or none. You'd need to synchronize populating and reading "queues" but that should be very cheap. As mjwills pointed out without getting some sort of "version" info from listener I don't see another obvious option.

Comment: Thanks Alexei but i think this is a silly option, definitely not the most realistic. The idea of n queues is absurd, especially when i asked for the most efficient option. I am still contemplating the best solution, from these suggestions and others.

Comment: @Raptop you claim that you must track result of "Subscriber reads message" call and subscribers can't do it themselves - I don't see how that can be done without some sort of per-subscriber data structure on provider's side... I would not go that way and instead change expectations/interface of subscribers - but you don't seem to be interested in that route.

Comment: My suggestion of passing a token, or hash with the notification i would think is a better solution. My issue with this approach is the value getting overwritten by the provider after the hash is compared but before the value is read by the subscriber.